# Can people who don’t believe, yet don’t not believe in Jesus Christ, still make it into heaven if they’re a good person?

Tags: sin, afterlife, non-christians

My boyfriend and I have gotten into many discussions. He’s mentioned “I don’t get it. I don’t *not* believe it him, but I can’t say I’m a whole hearted believer. Who’s to say I won’t go to heaven if it’s real? I’m a good person. Why do murderers who find Jesus only because they are imprisoned get to go to heaven, yet I’m sent to hell for simply not being 100% sure?”. He’s also mentioned “what if my perfect world is different from yours? Is heaven one solid thing, or will I have a perfect after life and you’ll have a different but still perfect heaven?”. He’s raised many questions and I think they’re good topics to talk about, since I have no clue.

Comment: you will get different answers depending on the denomination you ask. Which denomination POV would you like an answer from?

Comment: It depends on whether your own idea of a 'good' person is the same as God's estimation of what a 'good' person is. Since heaven is _His_ dwelling place and since _He_ has the keys, then it is _His_ estimation that matters. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Welcome to SE-C.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79245/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-viewpoints-on-the-eternal-destiny-of-individual

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to ignore the very wishy-washy "don't *not* believe" bit for a moment to just address "Can people who don’t believe [...] still make it into heaven if they’re a good person?". And the answer to that is:

### No

No one is a "good person". ***No one*** (Romans 3:10-12). "***All*** have sinned and fall short of the glory of God" (Romans 3:23). You will not gain Heaven through works: "no one comes to the Father except through [Jesus]" (John 14:6).

I realize there are probably some folks that consider themselves Christian out there that will disagree, but IMO, the Bible is pretty clear on this subject. We are saved by [grace alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_gratia).

All have sinned. All are *born* sinful, and are incapable of saving themselves... and yet, Christ died for *all* sin, no matter how heinous, and this is a *free gift*.

If you stop and think about it, this is also an excellent *logical* argument for Christianity being true. Christianity is, as far as I know, the only religion in which *you* can do *absolutely nothing* to "earn" salvation, and in which salvation has already been earned *for* you, and by God himself! This is contrary to Man's logic, which is why in every religion created by Man, one must *do something* to be saved. That makes sense to us, but "the word of the cross is folly to [unbelievers]" (1 Corinthians 1:18).

I might also add that those who believe in Sola Gratia consider it fundamental to Christian doctrine. Why? If you think about it, to deny Sola Gratia is to deny Christ. In order to say that "being good" is necessary for salvation, you must say either that Christ's death was insufficient, which is to lessen God, or worse, *unnecessary*. The theme of the entire scripture is that Christ, both true Man *and true God*, came not merely to be a good example, but *to bring Salvation*. If, therefore, you deny that Christ's death was *necessary*, you might want to seriously consider why you call yourself Christian. If you deny that it was *sufficient*, you call Him a liar, because on the cross he tells us "it is ***finished***" (John 19:30; another possible translation is "it is *accomplished*"). Not "I've done my part, now it's up to you". Christ Himself tells us clearly that his death *is* sufficient.

Moreover, why in Heaven would you *want* to believe in anything else? If you believe *you* must do something to "earn" Salvation, how can you ever know that you have done so? What a horrifying thought! Thanks be to God that we need do no such thing!

---

To more directly address some of the points you raise:

> I’m a good person.

You are not a good person. (I'm not a good person. Your pastor is not a good person. **No one** is a good person.) You are a sinner in need of Christ's forgiveness, and thanks be to God that he forgives you!

> I don’t not believe it him, but I can’t say I’m a whole-hearted believer.
> I’m sent to hell for simply not being 100% sure?

Be careful here, because this may be verging into works righteousness... and thank God for that! If salvation were dependent on our having absolute faith, I'm pretty sure we'd *all* be doomed. "Lord, I believe; help my unbelief!" (Mark 9:24)

I guess this is what you mean by "don't not believe". Your boyfriend might be more Christian than he realizes. How does one *not* obtain Grace? Well, one can obviously not *know* it is available (here we could get sidetracked into a whole other debate of the eternal fate of those that never heard of Christ), or one can *reject* the gift. Feeling uncertain is natural; I believe there are very few, if an, Christians who have not felt doubt on at least some occasions. For most, it is a constant struggle, but take comfort knowing that salvation is a gift that does not depend on anything *you* can do. On your own, you cannot even accept this gift, but it is the Spirit working *through* you which calls us to faith. Therefore, do not despair, neither let your heart be troubled, when the adversary and your own fallen nature causes you to doubt. Instead, I would commend you and your boyfriend to remain in the Church and in the Word. Surround yourselves with others that you may know God's love and know that you are not alone in your struggles.

---

You also had some interesting thoughts on the nature of heaven that aren't really on topic. I would encourage you to ask a separate question!

Comment: While I agree with the gist of your answer, the phrase `<whomever> is not a good person` is flawed. Being a sinner does not mean one isn't good, it means you aren't perfect and God is perfect and requires perfection, hence forgiveness and grace

Comment: @depperm, I am using "good" here in the Biblical sense (e.g. Genesis 1 and elsewhere), i.e. *God's* standard of "goodness" (which is synonymous with "perfect"). By that standard, the Bible clearly teaches that what I said is correct, and even your comment agrees. Since we are talking about obtaining Heaven by being "good", God's standard (as noted by Nigel J in a comment on the question) is the one that matters. Accordingly, I stand by what I said.

Comment: I don't believe the OP's definition/use of good was the same as yours. So the OP and future readers don't get confused, I might edit to be clearer that your use of good differs

Comment: @depperm, it probably wasn't. However, "make it into heaven if they’re a good person" is implicitly trying to equate a human definition with God's definition. My use of "good" in the sense the OP wants is deliberate. Put differently, whether one is "good" by some human definition is irrelevant in terms of Salvation. No benefit will come from using the word in that sense, and accordingly, I have no qualms discouraging such usage by whatever means.

Comment: I dissagree with this answer...it is fundamentally flawed. Jesus himself talked about entering the kingdom of heaven in Matthew 25...(I paraphrase part of the chapter) "some saying lord lord I did all these wonderful things in your name, the lord then replying who are you, I don't know you." He then talked of those who said, "lord I didn't know you, and Jesus replying, in as much as you did it to the least of these my brethren, you did it to me!" Read all of Matthew 25. You will find the answer to this question is yes but its not as simple as the O.P offers.

Comment: @Adam, do you then reject the epistles? Because Ephesians 2:8 in particular is *clear and explicit* in rejecting salvation via works. Moreover, note that those saved in Matthew 25 *did not know* they had done good works. This makes sense when you understand that good works are the *fruit* of faith, *not the cause*. Those condemned in the parable are not condemned because they have no works *as such*; rather, they have no works *because* they have no faith. Who is saved? "Whoever *believes* in [Jesus]" (John 3:16). Not whoever does good. To deny this is to deny the reason Christ died for us.

Comment: @Matthew the question is a bit broad as it doesn't ask for a specific denominations point of view. As such there are differing teachings on the subject (and it has been closed because of that). If you disagree you can post your own answer. This answer answers the question (it is an answer), contains scriptural sources (they support his view), and contains an explanation of the answer provided.

Comment: @Matthew Jesus point during his ministry was that we are not saved because we tick pharasee type boxes according to a scale. we are saved because we live according to our conscience. There are certainly those who will be in heaven who never knew God, however, they did follow the laws of God that are written on every persons heart. They demonstrate the fruits of the spirit, they do unto others as they would have others do unto themselves...showing compassion, feeding the hungry, providing shelter for the homeless etc.

Comment: @Adam, you are getting into [a whole other question](/questions/7323) here. Even so, *you yourself* are saying it is not *because* of works that we are saved, but rather that we might recognize faith *through* works. Even there, though, we must be careful, because (as *you* noted!) even evildoers can do good (Luke 11:13, Matthew 7:11). Again, what we see in Matthew 25 is that those who are saved recognized themselves as sinners, while those who were damned failed to recognize their sin. If you *think* you are good, you are almost certainly deluding yourself.

Comment: @Matthew you are missing a crucial point i made... conscience! Evil doers do good with the intent to corrupt. That is not acting in good conscience. Also, the fruits of the spirit are a physical demonstration of our faith. Faith without good works is dead. The pentecostal view that we can simply live in the spirit is bollocks. Jesus always taught, one must humble himself. It is through humility that even those who don't know jesus, will go to heaven. These are people who followed the laws God has written on every man's heart and demonstrate those innate fruits of the spirit.