# Which denominations teach that people who have not heard the Gospel can be saved through obedience to God?

Tags: soteriology, denomination-survey, comparative-christianity, obedience

According to the Catholics, Every man who is ignorant of the Gospel of Christ and of his Church, but seeks the truth and does the will of God in accordance with his understanding of it, can be saved.

Which denominations also teach that those who have not heard the Gospel and are ignorant of Christ can be saved if they seek the truth and obey God?

Comment: Related: [What is an overview of Christian viewpoints on the eternal destiny of individuals who die never hearing the Gospel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/79245/50422)

Comment: When you say denominations, are you asking for a list of Protestant sects with a similar view, or are you including the apostolic churches as well?

Answer (score 1):

Salvation for the dead is one of the [four primary missions](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/general-handbook/1-work-of-salvation-and-exaltation?lang=eng#title_number3) of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.

Extensive ancient and modern revelations and [teachings](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2012/10/the-joy-of-redeeming-the-dead?lang=eng) address this extremely important topic.

It is one of the primary reasons why the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints builds so many temples.
In these temples, each of which is called *The House of the Lord*, [we perform baptisms](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/comeuntochrist/uk/beliefs/temples) and other essential ordinances for those who died without a knowledge of the Gospel of Jesus Christ.

[Doctrine and Covenants section 138](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/138?lang=eng) contains a vision of the Savior's time in the spirit world, during which Peter says the Gospel was preached to the dead:

> Thus was the gospel preached to those who had died in their sins, without a knowledge of the truth, or in transgression, having rejected the prophets.
>
> These were taught faith in God, repentance from sin, vicarious baptism for the remission of sins, the gift of the Holy Ghost by the laying on of hands,
>
> And all other principles of the gospel that were necessary for them to know in order to qualify themselves that they might be judged according to men in the flesh, but live according to God in the spirit.
>
> And so it was made known among the dead, both small and great, the unrighteous as well as the faithful, that redemption had been wrought through the sacrifice of the Son of God upon the cross.
>
> Thus was it made known that our Redeemer spent his time during his sojourn in the world of spirits, instructing and preparing the faithful spirits of the prophets who had testified of him in the flesh;
>
> That they might carry the message of redemption unto all the dead, unto whom he could not go personally, because of their rebellion and transgression, that they through the ministration of his servants might also hear his words.

[Sections 124](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/124?lang=eng) and [128](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/128?lang=eng) give instructions to the saints to build a House of the Lord containing baptismal fonts matching the description of the one recorded in [1 Kings 7](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/1-kgs/7.23-26?lang=eng) as being in the temple Solomon built, and to perform baptisms for our deceased ancestors who died without a knowledge of the Gospel of Christ.

Malachi in the last verse of the Old Testament foretells a great calamity that would cover the Earth in the last days if we did not do this work:

> And he shall turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their fathers, lest I come and smite the earth with a curse.